# How to close an opencv imshow() window on Raspberry pi?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

On computer you can use a waitKey() fucntion to get command from the keyboard whereas on raspberry pi there's not a keyboard and I don't want to use ssh to kill the process but operate the raspberry pi only. How can I close a window on the pi only?

Answer (score 8):

You could use:

```
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.destroyWindow(winname)
```